# Why does a workload split up by setTimeout still freeze the browser?

Tags: javascript, v8

http://jsfiddle.net/Codemonkey/ye5qv/2/

I am experimenting with writing large workloads to recur using setInterval so that the browser can catch it's breath between each iteration of work. In my example above I'm giving the browser 100ms of rest between each interval of fibonacci calculations, but the browser is still frozen from the moment `fib()` is called to the moment the callback is called. *Note: In my example, the fibo function isn't called before one second after the document load so you can clearly see it freeze for a few seconds*

Exactly why isn't this method working, and how can I make it work? Alternatively, which other method could achieve the same goal result? To reiterate, the goal of using setInterval to split up the work is that the browser should ***never*** freeze or studder during the process.

*I'm using chrome and I'm mainly concerned with the V8 engine, but an x-browser compatible solution is a bonus*

Comment: I hope it's just an example. Do you know Binet's formula for Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: Yes, the only point of the fibo function is creating a workload that **will** cause the browser to freeze unless my method works

Comment: Your probably seeing reentry issues when the workload starts taking longer then 100ms. Use setTimeout instead and reset it each time the work finishes.  Edit - I see the fiddle does use setTimeout, but the question title says setInterval. Which is it?

Comment: @asawyer Whoops, the title was supposed to say setTimeout, didn't notice the mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your code never reaches the point where it calls `setTimeout` to give control back to the browser.

Change this:

```
for(var i = start; i < i+workload; i++)
```

to:

```
for(var i = start; i < start+workload; i++)
```

As `workload` is a positive number, `i < i + workload` will never be false, so you have an infinite loop.

---

You don't have to wait for 100 ms when giving control back to the browser, just calling `setTimout` is enough to make the browser handle events, so you can use the time 0:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  processor(start + workload);
}, 0);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/ye5qv/3/

Comment: I know that I don't need 100ms, but I was pretty aghast when "even 100ms was not enough". I didn't notice the loop blunder though, thanks

Comment: +1: this is better than my answer, I didn't notice the infinite loop- good catch. I got caught up in the details of what are true asynchronous operations in JS.

Comment: If you read the book ["High performance Java](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596802806.do) they say you actually do need to set the timeout to to around 25ms or else it the execution of the JavaScript blocks the redrawing of the page. This could be the cause of the blocking he mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, JavaScript's `setInterval` and `setTimeout` aren't truly asynchronous, so everything will still operate in a single thread. That means that when your `setInterval` callback is called, it runs in the main thread and blocks execution of everything else.

Here is a great post by John Resig which discusses this in detail: [How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

If you want truly asynchronous JavaScript, you must use something like [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers).

---

As others have pointed out here, in your particular case you actually have an infinite loop on this line:

```
for(var i = start; i < i+workload; i++)
```

Which is causing your code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    processor(start + workload);
}, 100);
```

To never be called. See [Guffa's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10949025/830125) for more information.

The rest of my answer still does apply though- if you're trying to do more than simple operations and animating a `.gif` simultaneously you may still have freezing or stuttering without using something like Web Workers.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I'm giving the setInterval a 100 ms pause, which should case the browser to unfreeze and do other things during those 100 ms, no? Can you comment on that

Comment: @Codemonkey: please see my edit. Guffa's answer is probably the one you want here.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in your code `setInterval` is actually never called, because in this line

```
for(var i = start; i < i+workload; i++)
```

the condition is always true since `i` is always smaller than `i+workload`, so it will never get out of the cycle. Good thing that you return from the function inside the loop.